# Handling different types of "follow" function efficiently in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

Here are the tables of the project

```
User
Car
CarPart
```

So in the project, user can follow multiple item types such as: another user, a car, a car sub-model, a car-part. This list might go long.

Technically, the first idea that comes into mind is to create 3 pivot tables and use foreign keys inside:

```
FollowUserUser
FollowUserCar
FollowUserCarPart
```

The question is, is this proper way to do it? 
Is there any other way to minimize table count as item types might increase in feature?

Comment: Seems reasonable to me.

Answer (score 0):

"Proper" is pretty subjective.

There are a few alternatives, each with trade-offs.

The design you describe requires one table per relationship, which means the number of joins to retrieve information about (for instance) a user increases with the number of relationships. That's not a problem from a performance point of view, but can make your queries complex. The design makes the links very explicit, which is usually helpful for future developers, and allows you to add custom data to each relationship - "user follows user" might have a "role" attribute (boss, colleague, friend etc.), which doesn't apply to "user follows car".

An alternative would be to have a single "relationships" table:

```
user_id
car_id
car_part_id
relationship_type
```

This allows you to capture the relationships in a single table, but you would still need all the joins to find out about a user, and it's not quite as expressive. You also can't store custom attributes of the relationship.